# How to extract last value in the URL before the last / separator using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this URL:

```
http://test.com/en/country/city
```

Im using **lastIndexOf** to obtain "city" but I want to obtain "country"

```
window.location.href.substring(window.location.href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
```

Is this posible with **lasIndexOf** or there is another function available for this case?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why dont you use url.split("/"); and url[urlArray.length-1] url[urlArray.length-2] to get city and country?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
var  fragment = "http://test.com/en/country/city";
var array_fragment = fragment.split('/');
var city = array_fragment[array_fragment.length - 1]
var country = array_fragment[array_fragment.length - 2]
alert(country)
```

Comment: Thank you. Easy to understand answer =)

Answer (score 3):

You can split your url by `/` and take needed element (first remove `http://` part):

```js
var str = 'http://test.com/en/country/city';

str = str.replace('http://', '');

var parts = str.split('/');
console.log(parts);

alert(parts[2]+', '+parts[3]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
var url = "http://test.com/en/country/city"
var urlParts = url.split("/")
urlParts[urlParts.length - 1] (which would equal to "city")
urlParts[urlParts.length - 2] (which would equal to "country")
```

Basically split on each occurence of `"/"` and pick the correct item from the returned array.

Answer (score 1):

Use split function to get second last value.

Try this

```
var url='http://test.com/en/country/city';

var splitArray=url.split('/');

alert(splitArray[splitArray.length-2]);
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is this posible with lastIndexOf?

**Yes, it is possible.**

Let's say

```
x="http://test.com/en/country/city"
```

We get the position of the last `/`

```
y=x.lastIndexOf("/");//26
```

We get the position of the second last `/`

```
z=x.lastIndexOf("/",y-1);//18
```

To extract the country, we now use `substring` as follows

```
x.substring(z+1,y)//country
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
var url = window.location.href;
var urlArray = url.split("/"); 

urlArray[urlArray.length-1] //City
urlArray[urlArray.length-2] //Country
```